# How to make RET insert a blank line and indent and put point on this line when point between `{}`?

Tags: javascript

In most JavaScript IDEs, there is a feature that pressing RET when point is between `{}`, results in an indented blank line with point on the end of this blank line, as shown in the following two pictures:

[image]

when pressing RET:

[image]

But I found the `electric-indent-mode` only do this:

[image]

How to make things happen just like the second picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something I use with `electric-pair-mode`:

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(defun my-electric-pair-post-self-insert-function (orig-fun)
  (let ((indent-after (and (eq last-command-event ?\n)
                           (< (1+ (point-min)) (point) (point-max))
                           (eq (save-excursion
                                 (skip-chars-backward "\t\s")
                                 (char-before (1- (point))))
                               (matching-paren (char-after))))))
    (apply orig-fun nil)
    (when indent-after
      (indent-according-to-mode)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-line 1)
        (indent-according-to-mode)))))
(advice-add 'electric-pair-post-self-insert-function :around #'my-electric-pair-post-self-insert-function)
```